# Error with custom elements tags in html angular

Tags: html, angular

Error: src/app/Pages/_layout/layout.component.html:96:7 - error NG8001: 'app-scroll-top' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-scroll-top' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-scroll-top' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

96       
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```html
<!--begin::Main-->
<ng-container *ngIf="selfLayout !== 'blank'; else blankLayout">
  <!-- begin:: Header Mobile -->
  <app-header-mobile
    #ktHeaderMobile
    id="kt_header_mobile"
    class="header-mobile align-items-center"
    [ngClass]="headerMobileClasses"
  ></app-header-mobile>
  <!-- end:: Header Mobile -->
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-root">
    <!--begin::Page-->
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-column-fluid page">
      <!-- begin:: Aside Left -->
      <ng-container *ngIf="asideSelfDisplay">
        <!--begin::STATIC Aside-->
        <!-- <app-aside
          #ktAside
          id="kt_aside"
          class="aside aside-left d-flex flex-column flex-row-auto"
          [ngClass]="asideCSSClasses"
        ></app-aside> -->
        <!--end::STATIC Aside-->

        <!--begin::DYNAMIC Aside-->
        <app-aside-dynamic
          #ktAside
          id="kt_aside"
          class="aside aside-left d-flex flex-column flex-row-auto"
          [ngClass]="asideCSSClasses"
        ></app-aside-dynamic>
        <!--end::DYNAMIC Aside-->
      </ng-container>
      <!-- end:: Aside Left -->

      <!--begin::Wrapper-->
      <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-row-fluid wrapper" id="kt_wrapper">
        <!-- begin:: Header -->
        <app-header
          #ktHeader
          id="kt_header"
          class="header"
          [ngClass]="headerCSSClasses"
        ></app-header>
        <!-- end:: Header -->

        <!-- begin:: Content -->
        <div
          class="content d-flex flex-column flex-column-fluid"
          id="kt_content"
          [ngClass]="contentClasses"
        >
          <!-- begin:: Content Head -->
          <ng-container *ngIf="subheaderDisplay">
            <app-subheader-wrapper></app-subheader-wrapper>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- end:: Content Head -->

          <!-- begin:: Content Body -->
          <ng-container *ngIf="contentExtended">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container *ngIf="!contentExtended">
            <!--begin::Entry-->
            <div class="d-flex flex-column-fluid">
              <!--begin::Container-->
              <div [ngClass]="contentContainerClasses">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                <!--end::Container-->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--end::Entry-->
          </ng-container>
          <!-- end:: Content Body -->
        </div>
        <!-- end:: Content -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="footerDisplay">
          <!--begin::Footer-->
          <app-footer
            class="footer bg-white py-4 d-flex flex-lg-column w-100"
            id="kt_footer"
            [ngClass]="footerCSSClasses"
          ></app-footer>
          <!--end::Footer-->
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <!--end::Wrapper-->
    </div>
    <!-- end:: Body -->
    <!--end::Page-->

    <!-- <app-toolbar></app-toolbar> -->

    <ng-container *ngIf="extrasScrollTopDisplay">
      <app-scroll-top></app-scroll-top>
    </ng-container>
    <!--end::Offcanvases-->
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #blankLayout>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-root">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<app-scripts-init></app-scripts-init>
<!--end::Main-->
```

```html
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  NgModule,
} from '@angular/core';
import { LayoutService, LayoutInitService } from '../../_metronic/core';
import KTLayoutContent from '../../../assets/js/layout/base/content';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.scss'],
})

export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  // Public variables
  selfLayout = 'default';
  asideSelfDisplay: true | undefined;
  contentClasses = '';
  contentContainerClasses = '';
  subheaderDisplay = true;
  contentExtended: false | undefined;
  asideCSSClasses: string | undefined;
  asideHTMLAttributes: any = {};
  headerMobileClasses = '';
  headerMobileAttributes = {};
  footerDisplay: boolean | undefined;
  footerCSSClasses: string | undefined;
  headerCSSClasses: string | undefined;
  headerHTMLAttributes: any = {};
  // offcanvases
  extrasSearchOffcanvasDisplay = false;
  extrasNotificationsOffcanvasDisplay = false;
  extrasQuickActionsOffcanvasDisplay = false;
  extrasCartOffcanvasDisplay = false;
  extrasUserOffcanvasDisplay = false;
  extrasQuickPanelDisplay = false;
  extrasScrollTopDisplay = false;
  @ViewChild('ktAside', { static: true }) ktAside: ElementRef | undefined;
  @ViewChild('ktHeaderMobile', { static: true }) ktHeaderMobile: ElementRef | undefined;
  @ViewChild('ktHeader', { static: true }) ktHeader: ElementRef | undefined;

  constructor(
    private initService: LayoutInitService,
    private layout: LayoutService
  ) {
    this.initService.init();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // build view by layout config settings
    this.selfLayout = this.layout.getProp('self.layout');
    this.asideSelfDisplay = this.layout.getProp('aside.self.display');
    this.subheaderDisplay = this.layout.getProp('subheader.display');
    this.contentClasses = this.layout.getStringCSSClasses('content');
    this.contentContainerClasses = this.layout.getStringCSSClasses(
      'content_container'
    );
    this.contentExtended = this.layout.getProp('content.extended');
    this.asideHTMLAttributes = this.layout.getHTMLAttributes('aside');
    this.asideCSSClasses = this.layout.getStringCSSClasses('aside');
    this.headerMobileClasses = this.layout.getStringCSSClasses('header_mobile');
    this.headerMobileAttributes = this.layout.getHTMLAttributes(
      'header_mobile'
    );
    this.footerDisplay = this.layout.getProp('footer.display');
    this.footerCSSClasses = this.layout.getStringCSSClasses('footer');
    this.headerCSSClasses = this.layout.getStringCSSClasses('header');
    this.headerHTMLAttributes = this.layout.getHTMLAttributes('header');
    // offcanvases
    if (this.layout.getProp('extras.search.display')) {
      this.extrasSearchOffcanvasDisplay =
        this.layout.getProp('extras.search.layout') === 'offcanvas';
    }

    if (this.layout.getProp('extras.notifications.display')) {
      this.extrasNotificationsOffcanvasDisplay =
        this.layout.getProp('extras.notifications.layout') === 'offcanvas';
    }

    if (this.layout.getProp('extras.quickActions.display')) {
      this.extrasQuickActionsOffcanvasDisplay =
        this.layout.getProp('extras.quickActions.layout') === 'offcanvas';
    }

    if (this.layout.getProp('extras.cart.display')) {
      this.extrasCartOffcanvasDisplay =
        this.layout.getProp('extras.cart.layout') === 'offcanvas';
    }

    if (this.layout.getProp('extras.user.display')) {
      this.extrasUserOffcanvasDisplay =
        this.layout.getProp('extras.user.layout') === 'offcanvas';
    }

    this.extrasQuickPanelDisplay = this.layout.getProp(
      'extras.quickPanel.display'
    );

    this.extrasScrollTopDisplay = this.layout.getProp(
      'extras.scrolltop.display'
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.ktAside) {
      for (const key in this.asideHTMLAttributes) {
        if (this.asideHTMLAttributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          this.ktAside.nativeElement.attributes[key] = this.asideHTMLAttributes[
            key
          ];
        }
      }
    }

    if (this.ktHeaderMobile) {
      for (const key in this.headerMobileAttributes) {
        if (this.headerMobileAttributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          this.ktHeaderMobile.nativeElement.attributes[
            key
          ] = this.headerMobileAttributes[key];
        }
      }
    }

    if (this.ktHeader) {
      for (const key in this.headerHTMLAttributes) {
        if (this.headerHTMLAttributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          this.ktHeader.nativeElement.attributes[
            key
          ] = this.headerHTMLAttributes[key];
        }
      }
    }
    // Init Content
    KTLayoutContent.init('kt_content');
  }
}
```

```html
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { InlineSVGModule } from 'ng-inline-svg';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages-routing.module';
import {
  NgbDropdownModule,
  NgbProgressbarModule,
} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { TranslationModule } from '../modules/i18n/translation.module';
import { LayoutComponent } from './_layout/layout.component';
import { ScriptsInitComponent } from './_layout/init/scipts-init/scripts-init.component';
import { HeaderMobileComponent } from './_layout/components/header-mobile/header-mobile.component';
import { AsideComponent } from './_layout/components/aside/aside.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './_layout/components/footer/footer.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './_layout/components/header/header.component';
import { HeaderMenuComponent } from './_layout/components/header/header-menu/header-menu.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './_layout/components/topbar/topbar.component';
import { ExtrasModule } from '../_metronic/partials/layout/extras/extras.module';
import { LanguageSelectorComponent } from './_layout/components/topbar/language-selector/language-selector.component';
import { CoreModule } from '../_metronic/core';
import { SubheaderModule } from '../_metronic/partials/layout/subheader/subheader.module';
import { AsideDynamicComponent } from './_layout/components/aside-dynamic/aside-dynamic.component';
import { HeaderMenuDynamicComponent } from './_layout/components/header/header-menu-dynamic/header-menu-dynamic.component';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({ 
  exports: [ LayoutComponent ],
  declarations: [
    LayoutComponent,
    ScriptsInitComponent,
    HeaderMobileComponent,
    AsideComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HeaderMenuComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    LanguageSelectorComponent,
    AsideDynamicComponent,
    HeaderMenuDynamicComponent,
    RouterModule
  ],
  imports: [
    LayoutComponent,
    CommonModule,
    PagesRoutingModule,
    TranslationModule,
    InlineSVGModule,
    ExtrasModule,
    NgbDropdownModule,
    NgbProgressbarModule,
    CoreModule,
    SubheaderModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

```html
import { HttpRequestService } from './core/models/interceptors/http-request/http-request.service';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/modules/shared/shared.module';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, LOCALE_ID, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { ClipboardModule } from 'ngx-clipboard';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { InlineSVGModule } from 'ng-inline-svg';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { CommonModule, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEs from '@angular/common/locales/es';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar'; 
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { AngularEditorModule } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';
import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import { BsModalService, ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import {MatDateFormats, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, NativeDateAdapter, DateAdapter} from '@angular/material/core';


registerLocaleData(localeEs, 'es');
// Highlight JS
import { HighlightModule, HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS } from 'ngx-highlightjs';
import xml from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/xml';
import json from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/json';
import scss from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/scss';
import typescript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/typescript';
import { SplashScreenModule } from './_metronic/partials/layout/splash-screen/splash-screen.module';
// #fake-start#
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './core/models/interceptors/error-handler/error-handler.service';
import { MaterialModule } from './modules/material/material.module';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatMomentDateModule, MomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import { SpinnerService } from './core/models/interceptors/spinner/spinner.service';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


// #fake-end#

function appInitializer() {
  return () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    });
  };
}

/**
 * Import specific languages to avoid importing everything
 * The following will lazy load highlight.js core script (~9.6KB) + the selected languages bundle (each lang. ~1kb)
 */
export function getHighlightLanguages() {
  return [
    { name: 'typescript', func: typescript },
    { name: 'scss', func: scss },
    { name: 'xml', func: xml },
    { name: 'json', func: json },
  ];
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SplashScreenModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularEditorModule,
    HighlightModule,
    SharedModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MomentDateModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    RouterModule,
    // #fake-start#fh
    // #fake-end#
    AppRoutingModule,
    InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule,
    NgIdleKeepaliveModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      closeButton: true,
      newestOnTop: true,
      progressBar: false,
      positionClass: "toast-top-right",
      preventDuplicates: false,
      timeOut: 5000,
      extendedTimeOut: 1000
    })
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es' },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [],
    },
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
        languages: getHighlightLanguages,
      },
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorHandlerService,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpRequestService,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: SpinnerService,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: you should ask a question and not only copy/paste all your code. anyway where is `app-scroll-top`? in which module is declared and more importantly, have you imported that module?

Comment: Where have you declared `app-scroll-top`? If it is a component, make sure you have declared it in your `AppModule`.

Answer (score 0):

For components to be usable, they have to be declared or imported to the module you want to use them in.

If the `ScrollTopComponent` is part of your `LayoutModule`, add it to the declarations.

If it is part of another module `SomeModule`, you have to add it to the declarations and exports of `SomeModule` and add `SomeModule` to the imports of `LayoutModule`.